# SSD Crucial P3 driver not accepted by Windows 11 system installation

Tags: ssd, windows-installer

I'm installing Windows 11 on a Dell [Latitude 5500](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-ie/latitude-15-5500-laptop/latitude_5500_setupspecs/%C3%BAlo%C5%BEi%C5%A1t%C4%9B?guid=guid-ba20ea28-ce42-45c5-8f32-a71d38922904) with replaced SSD (Crucial P3 PCIe 3.0).

Installation doesn't detect the HW, so I used Shf+F10 to initiate partition (HW is detected by BIOS and working for other OS types). Even when I copied driver to a USB thumb drive and copied the downloaded Crucial drivers pack from (https://www.crucial.com/support/ssd-support/p3-support) it doesn't detect the SSD for installation.

Is there a way **to force the default driver for installation**? It's strange that booting Windows 11 is able to see the disk and format partition by CLI, but is not able to pass this in GUI.

--Edit:

Drive was not use in RAID, also partition has been initiated during the windows 11 installation by the command line

--Edit2:
You are right Daniel, I even can format disk and copy file there from CLI. Unfortunately I cant skip the "pick up driver" screen in the installation process and continue system installation.
Unfortunately I have no log created at c: or x: The directory "$Windows.~BT" doesn't exit anywhere.

--Edit3:
I still have no solution for my Windows 10/11 installation problem. Any Linux distro has no issue with SSD and Windows is also able to use it by diskpart. I can't find any installation log file anywhere, as it's pre-installation phase, it possibly doesn't log anything as default.

Comment: Windows 11 ships with generic drivers for all NVMe SSDs. You do not need a driver. Something else is wrong here.

Comment: The driver you need is probably Intet RST/VMD (which you may want/try to disable in your UEFI settings instead).

Comment: has the drive previously be used as a RAID member? This also prevents the drive being used until the raid config on the disk has been cleared.

Comment: Even if not in RAID but already partitioned as MBR ("msdos") the installer will NOT allow installing Windows 11 because Windows 11 supports UEFI mode ONLY and, for Windows, that mode strictly requires GPT. That's likely the problem here but of course RAID is also a possibility.

Comment: Even when MBR-partitioned, drives _will_ show in Setup. I doubt there could be anything on the drive that would make Setup not show it.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, but how can you be sure it isn't showing up in the setup and the installer merely stating the OS can't be installed anywhere? Assuming this is the only drive present, that is the typical scenario that many users interpret and describe the same way as in this question.

Comment: [I’ll just leave this here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhhn0.png) // OP, please clarify what you actually see in that view. Since you apparently can interact with the drive using `diskpart`, I can only repeat my initial assessment: You do not have a driver problem. Maybe the setup log file will have helpful information. _While in Setup_, this file is at `X:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther`. Notepad is available for viewing it.